# glNormalPointer with interleaved array buffer

Tags: opengl

I create an interleaved vertex array in c++:

```
struct vertex
{
    GLfloat position[3];
    GLbyte normal[3];
};
std::vector< vertex > vertices;
// fill in vertices...
```

I copy the array to a gl buffer:

```
GLuint vertsBuffer;
glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertsBuffer);
glBufferData (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size () * sizeof (vertex), vertices.data (), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Is it possible to use glNormalPointer with interleaved data like this, for example?

```
glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertsBuffer);
glEnableClientState (GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
glNormalPointer (GL_BYTE, sizeof (vertex), (GLvoid*) offsetof (vertex, normal));
```

Or do I have to use glVertexAttribPointer instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work fine if you use the legacy `gl_Normal` [GLSL built-in (Section 7.3, page 49)](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.Full.1.20.8.pdf).

`glVertexAttribPointer()` is more forward-compatible though.

Comment: If you have a VBO bound it interprets the value of the pointer as an offset: **"If a non-zero named buffer object is bound to the GL_ARRAY_BUFFER target (see glBindBuffer) while a vertex array is specified, pointer is treated as a byte offset into the buffer object's data store.  Also, the buffer object binding (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING) is saved as vertex arrayclient-side state (GL_VERTEX_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING)."**

Comment: That's the second paragraph of the **Description** block by the way.

Comment: yeah, i think i should delete this question. sorry!